# Appending items to a list

Tags: python, list

I want to append items to a list. but only the middle item is added to the list. here is the code I have written.

```
while True:
    topping = input("Enter a topping which you want on your pizza: ")
    if topping != "quit":
        toppings = []
        toppings.append(topping)
        print("You have selected " + topping + " as a topping for your pizza")
    else:
        break
print("You have chosen ", end="")
print(toppings, end="")
print(" as toppings for your pizza")
```

Comment: You're recreating the list in every iteration of your loop, and only the last one makes it out of the loop. Define `toppings` before `while True`, and the code should work.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what you should do

```
toppings = []
while True:
    topping = input("Enter a topping which you want on your pizza: ")
    if topping != "quit":
        toppings.append(topping)
        print("You have selected " + topping + " as a topping for your pizza")
    else:
        break
print("You have chosen ", end="")
print(toppings, end="")
print(" as toppings for your pizza")
```

Since toppings was declared inside the loop, it was being initialised to an empty list at every iteration